# jquery validation: How to figure out the form associated with a validator?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Say I have the following validation (using jQuery validation plugin) set up,

```
  var validator = $("#name_change_form").validate({
    rules: {
      first_name: {
        required: true,
        regex: true
      },
      last_name: {
        required: true,
        regex: true
      }           
          },
    message: {
      first_name: "Please enter your first name",
      last_name: "Please enter your last name"
    },
    success: function(label) {
      // display success
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {      
      // diplay error 
    }
  });
```

Given the variable ***validator***, is there a way to figure out that it's associated with form whose id = "name_change_form"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<form>` element associated with the validator is available through its undocumented `currentForm` property:

```
var formId = validator.currentForm.id;  // "name_change_form"
```

Be careful though: again, this property is undocumented, so it might not exist anymore in future versions of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use `$(this).selector` to see what selector was used. You may also try `$(this).attr('id')` in success to see if that returns it? I don't have anything to test with currently and a bit busy.

Comment: `$(this).selector` will return the selector associated with the call to `$(this)`. Since no selector was passed (`this` is a DOM element, not a selector), it will return the empty string.